# IPC over memory mapped files

Tags: .net, ipc, rpc

I'm trying to find what is the idiomatic way to determine how to synchronize between reader and writer when doing IPC over memory mapped files.

In .NET, there is the `MemoryMappedViewStream`, which do act as a stream, *almost*.
It seems like it will always see the stream as the size of the block size and there is no way to continuously read from it.
(This question is not really .NET specific though)

So how is this done usually, do you use wait handles across processes to signal when its time to read/write?

Are there other ways to notify the reader when it is safe to read the shared buffer?

Comment: Using shared memory to implement IPC is pretty hard to get right.  It is the most basic kind of IPC, you must add the required synchronization yourself.  And .NET does not help, MMFs are only truly efficient when you use pointers to you can write directly to memory instead of having to serialize it.  The OS already provides decent wrappers around shared memory that do provide the convenience.  Named pipes and local-loopback sockets, their buffers are in the kernel memory pool.  Also requires serialization, tit for tat.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is what I am seeing right now, Named Pipes gave slightly better results than just gRPC (http/2 streams) over loopback. trying to do serialization over memory mapped files got super slow due to inter process sync using waithandles.

So I guess some message format more like Flatbuffers might work, if you could point their contents to the shared memory